# Cordova email composer 'isAvailable' error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, plugins, ionic-framework

I am using **Ionic Framework** and want too incorporate the `cordova email composer plugin`.

I did install the CLI :

`cordova plugin add https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer.git`

and used the default example given (my configured version ):

**Javascript**

```
app.controller('mailCtrl', ['$scope', '$cordovaEmailComposer' , function($scope, $cordovaEmailComposer) {

$scope.mailclient = function($cordovaEmailComposer)
{

$cordovaEmailComposer.isAvailable().then(function() {
   console.log("email available");
 }, function () {
   console.log("email not available");
 });

  var email = {
    to: 'rgeldenhuis@gmail.com',
    attachments: [
      '...\img\nslogo.png',
      '...\img\nslogo.png',
      '...\img\nslogo.png'
    ],
    subject: 'Truck Checked In',
    body: 'Hi',
    isHtml: true
  };

 $cordovaEmailComposer.open(email).then(null, function () {
   // user cancelled email
 });
 }
}]);
```

**HTML**

```
<ion-view view-title="Mail">          
 <ion-content ng-controller="mailCtrl">

   <button ng-click="mailclient(email)" class="button button-icon icon ion-email">
      Send mail
   </button>

 </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

I know it will not work on the browser I have tested it using the Ionic view app, but it doesn't do anything.

on the browser console I receive this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'isAvailable' of undefined.

is this a normal issue or am I using the coding wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have to include `$cordovaEmailComposer` as param of controller function not in function `$scope.mailclient`. Then it should works.

```
app.controller('mailCtrl', function($scope, $cordovaEmailComposer) {
...
}
```

Then your plugin isn't install properly. Did you call?

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer.git
```

Comment: I did at first but I get this error then. `ionic.bundle.js:25642 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $cordovaEmailComposerProvider <- $cordovaEmailComposer <- mailCtrl`

Comment: I tried it. After I have install the plugin with `cordova plugin add https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-email-composer.git`, I don't get a provider error.

Comment: Do you find the directory `cordova-plugin-email-composer` under `plugins/`?

Comment: Yes it is there, it should work I have followed all instructions correctly.

Comment: Is this your first cordova plugin? you have to add `ngCordova` to your angular module. -> `angular.module('myApp', ['ngCordova'])`

Comment: Did you try to remove your platform and then add again? Sometimes it helps, but otherwise I can't help you, sorry.

Comment: yes I have replaced it but still nothing thanks for the help.

Comment: Hi , I have the same issue , did you find a solution please ?

Answer (score 0):

The dependency injections array is missing a closing square bracket in the controller. Remove the closing bracket from the end of the controller. Like this:

```
app.controller('mailCtrl', ['$scope', '$cordovaEmailComposer' ] , 
 function($scope, $cordovaEmailComposer) {
});
```

Also plugin calls are to be included within deviceready event of cordova. It makes sure that the device is loaded before making a plugin call.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
   // plugin call
}, false);
```

Read this [ngCordova issues](http://ngcordova.com/docs/common-issues/):